# Rails - How to customize URL instead of showing ID for SEO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, search-engine

I'm working with a Rails application with article resources. Currently, the pages are indexed by Google like this, http://domain.com/article/id. But I know that this is not very descriptive for SEO purposes and I wonder if I can include the title of the article in there.

I'm not sure about the format though. Could I do it like http://domain.com/article/id/title-of-article. Not sure about the standard way to do this. Any ideas would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Friendly ID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), tutorial is [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid). Very simple and quite good stuff.

It lets you to use name or title instead of id in the url.

Comment: What if I do not have a unique field to use for the url? Can I use the name attribute along with the id to make sure it's unique?

Comment: Lots of CMSes use domain.com/article/title-of-article-id for this purpose, e.g. foo.com/article/a-great-title-37573626. If the article title might change in the future, you can use the id to redirect to the most recent url.

Comment: The tutorial I linked contains solution for that also. However friendly id makes the name unique and url friendly, if you only concerned about uniqueness.